# HTTP 1.0 vs 1.1

Tags: http, http-1.1, http-1.0

Could somebody give me a brief overview of the differences between HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1.1?  I've spent some time with both of the RFCs, but haven't been able to pull out a lot of difference between them.  Wikipedia says this:

> **HTTP/1.1 (1997-1999)**
>
> Current version; persistent connections enabled by default and works well with proxies. Also supports request pipelining, allowing multiple requests to be sent at the same time, allowing the server to prepare for the workload and potentially transfer the requested resources more quickly to the client.

But that doesn't mean a lot to me.  I realize this is a somewhat complicated subject, so I'm not expecting a full answer, but can someone give me a brief overview of the differences at a bit lower level?
By this I mean that I'm looking for the info I would need to know to implement either an HTTP server or application. I'm mostly looking for a nudge in the right direction so that I can figure it out on my own.

Comment: Good on you for going to the source. It sounds like you don't kno wmuch about networking in general, if you don't understand that summary. Perhaps you should research those terms as well.

Comment: Although I am still a newbie when it comes to this stuff, my primary issue is that the summary gives me more the "whats" rather than the "hows."

Comment: [RFC 2616, Section 19.6.1: "Changes from HTTP/1.0"](http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.19.6.1)

Comment: http://www8.org/w8-papers/5c-protocols/key/key.html

Answer (score 413, accepted):

**Proxy support and the Host field:**

HTTP 1.1 has a required Host header by spec.

HTTP 1.0 does not officially require a Host header, but it doesn't hurt to add one, and many applications (proxies) expect to see the Host header regardless of the protocol version.

Example:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.blahblahblahblah.com
```

This header is useful because it allows you to route a message through proxy servers, and also because your web server can distinguish between different sites on the same server.

So this means if you have blahblahlbah.com and helohelohelo.com both pointing to the same IP.  Your web server can use the Host field to distinguish which site the client machine wants.

**Persistent connections:**

HTTP 1.1 also allows you to have persistent connections which means that you can have more than one request/response on the same HTTP connection.

In HTTP 1.0 you had to open a new connection for each request/response pair.  And after each response the connection would be closed.   This lead to some big efficiency problems because of [TCP Slow Start](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-start).

**OPTIONS method:**

HTTP/1.1 introduces the OPTIONS method.  An HTTP client can use this method to determine the abilities of the HTTP server.  It's mostly used for Cross Origin Resource Sharing in web applications.

**Caching:**

HTTP 1.0 had support for caching via the header: If-Modified-Since.

HTTP 1.1 expands on the caching support a lot by using something called 'entity tag'. 
If 2 resources are the same, then they will have the same entity tags.

HTTP 1.1 also adds the If-Unmodified-Since, If-Match, If-None-Match conditional headers.

There are also further additions relating to caching like the Cache-Control header.

**100 Continue status:**

There is a new return code in HTTP/1.1 100 Continue.  This is to prevent a client from sending a large request when that client is not even sure if the server can process the request, or is authorized to process the request.  In this case the client sends only the headers, and the server will tell the client 100 Continue, go ahead with the body.

**Much more:**

- Digest authentication and proxy authentication
- Extra new status codes
- Chunked transfer encoding
- Connection header
- Enhanced compression support
- Much much more.

Comment: Note that a lot of servers/proxies that claim they want HTTP/1.0 will get very upset if you omit the Host header.

Comment: HTTP 1.0 does have support for compression via the Content-Encoding header. 

As Paul mentioned, I would definitely recommend any HTTP/1.0 clients to send the Host header, since it isn't strictly prohibited to do so and things will more often work as you expect them to.

Otherwise, this is dead on.

Comment: Regarding "if you have blahblahlbah.com and helohelohelo.com both pointing to the same IP. Your web server can use the Host field to distinguish which site the client machine wants." So what happens when a HTTP 1.0 client gives us no host field to distinguish?

Comment: @Pacerier usually a default page of some sort; it depends on the server.

Comment: @Amazed, hmm what's the best way to manage this dilemna? For example, what methods do companies usually employ?

Comment: @Pacerier some companies will serve up their own home page, others will serve an error page, others will not provision for this at all and will serve up whatever the server software's default page is (e.g. my site's shared host responds with [The HTTP service is functioning correctly.](https://216.18.212.66/) and nothing else.) It's not usually possible to figure out which domain is being asked for without the `Host:` header.

Answer (score 24):

 HTTP 1.0 (1994)

- It is still in use
- Can be used by a client that cannot deal with chunked
  (or compressed) server replies

 HTTP 1.1 (1996- 2015)

- Formalizes many extensions to version 1.0
- Supports persistent and pipelined connections
- Supports chunked transfers, compression/decompression
- Supports virtual hosting (a server with a single IP Address hosting multiple domains)
- Supports multiple languages
- Supports byte-range transfers; useful for resuming interrupted data
  transfers

HTTP 1.1 is an enhancement of HTTP 1.0. The following lists the
four major improvements:

1. Efficient use of IP addresses, by allowing multiple domains to be
   served from a single IP address.
2. Faster response, by allowing a web browser to send multiple
   requests over a single persistent connection.
3. Faster response for dynamically-generated pages, by support for
   chunked encoding, which allows a response to be sent before its
   total length is known.
4. Faster response and great bandwidth savings, by adding cache
   support.

Answer (score 12):

For trivial applications (e.g. sporadically retrieving a temperature value from a web-enabled thermometer) HTTP 1.0 is fine for both a client and a server.  You can write a bare-bones socket-based HTTP 1.0 client or server in about 20 lines of code.

For more complicated scenarios HTTP 1.1 is the way to go.  Expect a 3 to 5-fold increase in code size for dealing with the intricacies of the more complex HTTP 1.1 protocol.  The complexity mainly comes, because in HTTP 1.1 you will need to create, parse, and respond to various headers.  You can shield your application from this complexity by having a client use an HTTP library, or server use a web application server.

Answer (score 8):

A key compatibility issue is support for [persistent connections](http://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup?doc=2616#section-8).  I recently worked on a server that "supported" HTTP/1.1, yet failed to close the connection when a client sent an HTTP/1.0 request.  When writing a server that supports HTTP/1.1, be sure it also works well with HTTP/1.0-only clients.

Comment: Does HTTP/1.1 require us to be HTTP/1.0 compatible?

Comment: @Troy - Is it valid to send a response to an HTTP 1.1 request and immediately afterwards close the connection (socket that the request was read from on the server) ? Which practically means that the server implements HTTP 1.0

Answer (score 5):

One of the first differences that I can recall from top of my head are multiple domains running in the same server, partial resource retrieval, this allows you to retrieve and speed up the download of a resource (it's what almost every download accelerator does).

If you want to develop an application like a website or similar, you don't need to worry too much about the differences but you **should** know the difference between `GET` and `POST` verbs at least.

Now if you want to develop a browser then yes, you will have to know the complete protocol as well as if you are trying to develop a HTTP server.

If you are only interested in knowing the HTTP protocol I would recommend you starting with HTTP/1.1 instead of 1.0.

Comment: Methinks Jason already knows the difference between GET and POST if he's considering building his own HTTP Server/app from the ground up. :)

Comment: I've actually done some work with a webserver that currently only supports HTTP 1.0, I was just wondering what is involved in adding 1.1 support.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP 1.1 is the latest version of Hypertext Transfer Protocol, the World Wide Web application protocol that runs on top of the Internet's TCP/IP suite of protocols. compare to HTTP 1.0 , HTTP 1.1 provides faster delivery of Web pages than the original HTTP and reduces Web traffic.

Web traffic Example: For example, if you are accessing a server. At the same time so many users are accessing the server for the data, Then there is a chance for hanging the Server. This is Web traffic.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP 1.1 comes with the host header in its specification while the HTTP 1.0 doesn't officially have a host header, but it doesn't refuse to add one.

The host header is useful because it allows the client to route a  message throughout the proxy server, and the major difference between 1.0 and 1.1 versions HTTP are:

1. HTTP 1.1 comes with persistent connections which define that we can have more than one request or response on the same HTTP connection.
2. while in HTTP 1.0 you have to open a new connection for each request and response
3. In HTTP 1.0 it has a pragma while in HTTP 1.1 it has Cache-Control
   this is similar to pragma