# What are the differences between HTTP 1.0 and 1.1?

Tags: http, http-headers

The latest StackOverflow [podcast](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/podcast-44/) has piqued my interest in the differences between HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1.1.

Can anyone provide a simple list of the major differences between the HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1.1 specifications?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246859/http-1-0-vs-1-1/247026#247026

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Didn't come up on a search for some reason.

Comment: I find the search box to be pretty weak, but for some reason the background search performed while asking a question returns good results. I usually type a title on the Ask Question page, focus the body and wait to see if I get any decent results before actually posting.

Comment: Although to make me look a fool, posting this exact question on the Ask Question page fails with a "add more unique words" message.

Answer (score 7):

Have you checked [HTTP/1.1 – 19.6.1 Changes from HTTP/1.0](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.6.1)?