# Does DNS Server redirect a request to the IP directly or gives back the IP to the asking client?

Tags: http, dns, httpwebrequest

So a book I am reading has this nice image:

[image]

So it is suggested that once a client asks a DNS server an IP for a host, actually the DNS server does not respond back with the IP but rather find the IP, send the same request to the ip but the response comes back to the client..

This is very confusing for me since the accepted answer here: [Http Request Life Cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814514/http-request-life-cycle) does not fit with this one at all.

Which is correct?

Comment: The one in [Http Request Life Cycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814514/http-request-life-cycle) is the correct one. DNS doesn't know anything about the applications that use it and a DNS server will definitely not make requests to a web server on a client's behalf.

Comment: i have created an extensive answer for this commonly asked question here: https://github.com/hardikvasa/http-connection-lifecycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That image is completely wrong. It would probably be a good idea to stop reading that book.