# Laravel passing data from Controller to view without refreshing

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

I'm pretty new to Laravel and I'm trying to pass data from my controller to the view, which I managed to do as follows:

Controller:

```
$data['value1'] = 1;
return view('main', $data);
```

main.blade.php:

```
{{value1}}
```

This works fine but now my question is what can I do if I want to change the value of `value1` with another method of the controller **without** refreshing the page?

Are there different approaches or is there one which is most used in Laravel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start there, it talk about HTTP request lifecyle https://stackoverflow.com/a/4814789/5543999 and then read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49376645/5543999

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a front-end framework. Check out React / Vue / Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without refresh you need to implement a kind background task which pulls the data to frontend.
You could do this out of the box with https://laravel-livewire.com/ or implement it via vuejs.