# What is different between HttpCacheability.NoCache and Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"?

Tags: c#, asp.net

what is the different between the two lines below? :

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

and

```
 Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read through the documentation, generally, there isn't any difference at all.

However, since the former uses the Cache object (`HttpCachePolicyBase` in Asp.Net 4 or Asp.Net MVC) it provides:

a) An abstraction over the response object's caching policy that can be useful in testing scenarios

b) Potential future-proofing if the HTTP spec is extended for some reason to mean that `NoCache` needs more headers in the response, or other tweaks to the response.

It also allows the notion of 'non-cacheability' to be adapted according to the capabilities of the client transparently; which is important in the case that HTTP does evolve - but also already in the case of HTTP 1.0 and 1.1 clients (differences between 1.0 and 1.1 are well-summarised in [HTTP 1.0 vs 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246859/http-1-0-vs-1-1)).

In the second line, you are taking responsibility for how the no-cache directive is applied (using a somewhat magic string) - granted, it's still testable, but if the HTTP spec does change then you have to code around it yourself.

Ultimately, it's better design to use the `Response.Cache` object than to code the headers directly (it really comes into its own for ETags and If-Not-Modified-Since handling, for example).

Answer (score 1):

The `Response.CacheControl` property is only maintained for backwards compatibility. When you assign a string to it, it will set the corresponding value in the `Response.Cache` object.