# Code difference between HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1.1

Tags: http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTTP 1.0 vs 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246859/http-1-0-vs-1-1)

I have learnt about the difference between the HTTP 1.0 and 1.1. 
In the former, for obtaining each resource form the same server we use new connections where as in the latter we use the same connection. I searched in the net  for code fragments to justify the statement(such as mozilla etc) but I was not able to find it. Can you please help me to find the same.

Comment: Have you looked at the [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616)?

Answer (score -1):

The diffences are e.g.:

- reusage of a conneciton
- usage of hostnames (helpful for shared hosting)
- OPTIONS header for checking metainformations
- Caching with Expires, Etag and Last-Modified