# How do I get the domain originating the request in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using express.js and I need to know the domain which is originating the call. This is the simple code

```
app.get(
    '/verify_license_key.json',
    function( req, res ) {
        // do something
```

How do I get the domain from the `req` or the `res` object?
I mean I need to know if the API was called by `somesite.example` or `someothersite.example`.
I tried doing a console.dir of both `req` and `res` but I got no idea from there, also read the documentation but it gave me no help.

Comment: try: `req.host` or `req.get('host')`  [expresses docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.host)

Comment: node.js: `req.headers["x-forwarded-for"] || req.connection.remoteAddress` [x-forwarded-for](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) would cover your bases behind a proxy, load balancer...

Comment: I get this warning: express deprecated req.host: Use req.hostname instead index.js:20:8

Comment: *"I need to know if the API was called by somesite.example"*. Note that the domain *example.com* is reserved specifically for use in examples: https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You have to retrieve it from the [`HOST` header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247026).

```
var host = req.get('host');
```

It is optional with HTTP 1.0, but required by 1.1. And, the app can always impose a requirement of its own.

---

If this is for supporting [cross-origin requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), you would instead use the `Origin` header.

```
var origin = req.get('origin');
```

Note that some cross-origin requests require validation through a ["*preflight*" request](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests):

```
req.options('/route', function (req, res) {
    var origin = req.get('origin');
    // ...
});
```

---

If you're looking for the client's IP, you can retrieve that with:

```
var userIP = req.socket.remoteAddress;
```

- [`message.socket`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_socket).
- [`socket.remoteAddress`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_remoteaddress)

Note that, if your server is behind a proxy, this will likely give you the proxy's IP. Whether you can get the user's IP depends on what info the proxy passes along. But, it'll typically be in the headers as well.

Comment: But doesn't this give me the host of the api?It might be caused by the fact that i'm doing this locally and i have api.time.ly set to resolve to 127.0.0.1 and the call i'm making is from localhost ,but if i use that, host is "api.time.ly" i need to know the domain which is calling me. i will test this on a live site.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti I guess I don't understand what you mean by "*the domain which is calling me*." HTTP clients don't typically supply their own hostname in the request. Is this for [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)?

Comment: I've got a central api which is located at api.time.ly. This api is called by different client websites which install our wordpress plugin. So we could have http://church1.com and http://sauna1.com make calls to our api. In the API would i be able to get if the call was made from http://church1.com or from http://sauna1.com? i saw a header `'user-agent': 'WordPress/3.6; http://localhost/wordpress_clean'` should i parse that?

Comment: If Domain is not passed, it's not a problem, i can add it to the API call obviously.

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti You can try splitting and [parsing](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) the user-agent or requiring it as data in the request. But, I'd say something like [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) would be better suited for identifying clients.

Comment: Hi, probably passing the parameter in the call is the best option, i just need to know the domain to perform some checks to see if the same licence is used on more than one site. I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: It doesn't work for domains such as mydomain.ninja

Answer (score 55):

Instead of:

```
var host = req.get('host');
var origin = req.get('origin');
```

you can also use:

```
var host = req.headers.host;
var origin = req.headers.origin;
```

Comment: getting `undefined`

Comment: gives me 127.0.0.1:3000

Comment: 127.0.0.1:3000  is similar to `localhost:3000` I believe. `127.0.0.1` refers to the local IP address

Answer (score 17):

In Express 4.x you can use `req.hostname`, which returns the domain name, without port. i.e.:

```
// Host: "example.com:3000"
req.hostname
// => "example.com"
```

See: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.hostname

Comment: This returns hostname of the server you are receiving request on. It **will work only if** you are running your API and website on the same server and originating and receiving party is the same host.

Comment: this returns the hostname of the server that is hosting the code, not the originating.....

Comment: "Contains the hostname derived from the Host HTTP header", and " The Host request header specifies the host and port number of the server to which the request is being sent"... So this is not the origin...

Answer (score 6):

`req.get('host')` is now deprecated, using it will give `Undefined`.

Use,

```
    req.header('Origin');
    req.header('Host');
    // this method can be used to access other request headers like, 'Referer', 'User-Agent' etc.
```

Answer (score 6):

Year 2022, I use express v4.17.1 get following result

> var host = req.get('host');         // works,    localhost:3000

> var host = req.headers.host;        // works,    localhost:3000

> var host = req.hostname;            // works,    localhost

> var origin = req.get('origin');     // not work, undefined

> var origin = req.headers.origin;    // not work, undefined

> [image]

Comment: var host = req.get('host'); // works, localhost:3003 // server host, no origin (3000)...