# Restrict access to Node.js using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, restriction

I do have a running node.js script located in a server.
What i want is that it doesn't get directly accessed from browser and also i want that only certain domains/IP-s can call it!
Is it possible?!

Comment: For as far as i know Express isn't able to do conditional blocks on it's own like Nginx and Apache can. So i'm out of ideas at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to distinguishing between accessing something from a browser as opposed to other software, but restricting access to some domains/IPs should be doable. The following (non production) code to restrict access to the localhost loop back might serve as a starting point:

```
function securityCheck( req, response, next)
{    var callerIP = req.connection.remoteAddress;
     (callerIP == "::ffff:127.0.0.1" || callerIP == "::1") ? next() : reply404( response);
}

function reply404( response)
{   response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
    response.statusMessage = "Not Found";
    console.log("reply404: statusCode: " + response.StatusCode);
    response.end('<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size:200%;">ERROR 404 &ndash; Not Found<\/span>');
}
var app = express();
app.use(securityCheck);  // restrict access
... // continue with app routing
```

See also more detailed SO answers to [Express.js: how to get remote client address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849687/express-js-how-to-get-remote-client-address) and [How do I get the domain originating the request in express.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498726/how-do-i-get-the-domain-originating-the-request-in-express-js)