# How to customize remote api call?

Tags: node.js, api

I write a signup webpage with `nodejs`, and in this webpage, I use `ajax` to call the function `signup` like this

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "/signup",
  data: { tel: tel, password: password}
})
```

And in `app.js`, the `signup` function like this

```
.post('/signup', async (ctx) => {
   //do something
})
```

And now everyone can call the `signup` function with the url `http://domain/signup` without visiting the signup webpage, I think it's a mistake, I only want the local program can call this function, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Typically it's either [API Keys](https://stormpath.com/blog/express-sample-api-key-management) for doling out general access, or IP-based restrictions at either the application or network level.

API Keys are a token that identifies and authenticates an endpoint. You can also use it to track usage and/or ban abuse. For example, see Google Maps' [documentation about using their API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key). Then all API calls have that key:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap
```

This allows the server to parse the key, check against it's key database or whatever, and allow access. You'll **need** to use HTTPS for this if it's over any public network.

IP or other network restrictions are [easier to setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235117/restrict-access-to-node-js-using-express#35235649) and best when you have a 1:1 relationship with your API. That is, your application alone accesses this API, and you control all the servers, etc.