# How do I get the domain originating the request (of the front-end) in NestJS

Tags: nestjs

My question is similar to the following: [How do I get the domain originating the request in express.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498726/how-do-i-get-the-domain-originating-the-request-in-express-js) but I'm using NestJS.
I found that there might be a good answer for express.js, but I cannot apply it on NestJS (req.origin is undefined).

Could anyone help me with this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you try to access request?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer for my question, we can use @Host('origin'). The value exists only when we call the back-end server from a real front-end, not from Postman or directly call back-end url from browser.
Thank you Moazzam Arif for helping, allow use your example to show my answer below.

```
@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  @Get()
  findAll(@Host('origin') origin: string): string {
    return 'This action returns all cats';
  }
}
```

Comment: If you set the Origin header in Postman it will work

Comment: There is no @Host decorator in nestjs.. is it custom decorator?

Comment: did you mean `@Headers()` instead of `@Host()` ?

Answer (score 6):

In my project below code is worked.

```js
async login (@Headers() headers) {
  console.log('AUTHH LOGG', headers.host)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If running `@Headers()` like this...

```js
import { Get, Request, Headers } from '@nestjs/common';

@Get()
findAll(@Headers() headers: Headers) {
  console.log(headers);
}
```

it gives you

```json
{
  "host": "localhost:3001",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"100\"",
  "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
  "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) OtherShtuff",
  "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"Windows\"",
  "origin": "http://localhost:3000",
  "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
  "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
  "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
  "referer": "http://localhost:3000/",
  "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
  "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,de;q=0.6",
  "cookie": "_ga=GA1blahblahblah"
}
```

so to get the actual host origin as asked, using the below works. However, using `@Headers() headers: Header` then calling headers.origin causes typescript errors since Headers doesn't define all the parameters above. So you'd have to define it yourself, so I would stick to one of the two options below.

```js
import { Get, Headers } from '@nestjs/common';

@Get()
findAgain(@Headers('origin') origin: string) {
  console.log(origin);
}

// or 

@Get()
findEvenMore(@Request() req: Request) {
  console.log(req.get("origin"));
  console.log(req.headers.origin);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

from [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers), you can have access to request object in Nestjs.

> Nest provides access to the request object of the underlying platform
>   (Express by default). We can access the [request object](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req) by instructing
>   Nest to inject it by adding the @Req() decorator to the handler's
>   signature.

```
@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  @Get()
  findAll(@Req() request: Request): string {
    return 'This action returns all cats';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the controller use the @Req() decorator to access the request object and req.get('origin') will give you the domain from which the request originated

```
    @Get()
    async testAPIKey(@Req() req, @Headers() headers) {
       const origin = req.get('origin');
       console.log(origin) // This will return the origin.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want to have it. Besides from the all answers bellow, you can also extract from Request object in custom guard/interceptor by:

```
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';

@Injectable()
export class Your_Custom_Guard_Name_Class implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    // Headers object contains all what you need
    const { host } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest().headers; 
      // Your code
    } 
  }
}
```

And use it in your controller like:

```
@UseGuards(Your_Custom_Guard_Name_Class)
@Post('endpointWithCustomGuard')
async login() {
  ...
}
```