# Express.js Find URL of client consuming REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, express

Lets say, I have a server running at: `https://example.com`
The code in server:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
  let data = {'Hello':'World'}
  res.json(data);
});

app.post('/',(req, res)=>{
  let name = req.body.name;
  let email = req.body.email;
  res.json({name, email});
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Now, there is a client: `https://website.com`, trying to access server response by making a **GET** and **POST** request. `(No API key is required)`

How can the server find the web address of the client?
In this example, I want the server `(example.com)` to determine the client's URL `(website.com)` and save it in the database. `req.hostname()` is not giving the desired output..

Comment: possibly the answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498726/how-do-i-get-the-domain-originating-the-request-in-express-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express.js: how to get remote client address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849687/express-js-how-to-get-remote-client-address)

Comment: Thank you. I read those Posts before posting this question. I didn't get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[req.hostname](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.hostname) is what you're looking for.

**Update:**

After re-reading your question, I think what you want is identifying [cross-origin requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), you would instead use the `Origin` header.

```
var origin = req.get('origin');
```

Note that some cross-origin requests require validation through a ["*preflight*" request](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-preflight-requests):

```
req.options('/route', function (req, res) {
    var origin = req.get('origin');
    // ...
});
```

Comment: It will give me `example.com` but I want `website.com`

Comment: I've updated my answer, please see if that's what you're looking for

Comment: Thank you Tudor, This is what I want.