# How can i know which app or website is accessing my nodejs api

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to obtain the app package name and website url for any app or website that accesses my api in node js

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498726/how-do-i-get-the-domain-originating-the-request-in-express-js

Comment: @treecon how can i get an app name because that is just for websites