# How to know the domain of the website from where we are getting a request to our API service?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I'm building a web site using ReactJs(for frontend) and NodeJS(for backend API service).
Now I have an issue of authentication for my API service so I decided to add authentication using domain checking. Which means I want to accept the request to my API service from only specific domains those are my domain and and my localhost.
**So, help me to know the domain or URL of the web site from where we are getting request to access our API service.**

**I have tried this it works, but it is get URL of the domain where I have hosted my API service.**

```
const url = require('url');
const dns = require('dns');


exports.checkip= (requestip) => {
   let link = requestip
   console.log(link)
   link == "/" ? link = "http://localhost" : link = link
   console.log(link) 
   const parsedUrl = url.parse(link); // Parse the URL
   const domain = parsedUrl.hostname; // Extract the domain from the parsed URL


   // return Apikeys.includes(link)
   return Apikeys.includes(domain)

   dns.lookup(domain, (err, address, family) => { // Use DNS module to look up IP address
       if (err) {
           console.error(err);
           res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to lookup IP address for the domain' });
           return false
       } else {
           res.json({ domain, ipAddress: address ,family});
           return true
       }
   });

}
```

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498726/how-do-i-get-the-domain-originating-the-request-in-express-js

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CORS](https://aws.amazon.com/what-is/cross-origin-resource-sharing/) policy to limit requests to specific domains.

However, note that **relying solely** on the request for security is not sufficient as attackers can forge a request from a trusted domain, and thus it cannot replace server protection (like authentication mechanism)