# Why is a raw HTTP request extremely slow?

Tags: http, rust

When I try to send HTTP request packets using sockets it is extremely slow. It takes about 30 seconds to get a reply whereas in any other language with the same base code it takes 1 second.

```
use std::old_io::BufferedStream;
use std::old_io::TcpStream;

fn main() {
    let mut reddit = BufferedStream::new(TcpStream::connect("reddit.com:80").unwrap());
    reddit.write_all(format!("GET / HTTP/1.1{0}User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3{0}Host: www.reddit.com{0}Accept: */*{0}{0}", "\r\n").as_bytes());
    reddit.flush();
    let reply = reddit.read_to_string().unwrap();
    println!("{}", reply);
}
```

Is this a bug in Rust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are using HTTP 1.1, which [allows *persistent connections*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/247026/155423). 30 seconds is probably the timeout of the server on the other end.

Switch to HTTP 1.0 or properly close the connection, perhaps by using the header `Connection: close`. Doing either of these reduces the run time to ~170ms, without enabling any compile-time optimizations (which probably don't do much here anyway).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `Connection:close`? I cannot seem to find any reference to it. Is it part of the standard library?

Comment: Edit: nvm - I understand that `Connection : close` is the header included in the request for HTTP 1.1 to avoid(turn off) persistent connections.