# .NET 5 Exception Throwing Content Stream Error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

I'm upgrading a project to .NET 5.0 and one of our exception extension classes fails in tests where others pass.  This is only a problem in .NET 5.0 where it works fine in .NET Core 3.1.

Examples of the two exceptions being thrown in code that the tests check:

```cs
if (request.GroupId <= 0)
{
    throw new BadRequestException($"A valid {nameof(Data.Models.Group)} Id must be provided.");
}

var group = await Database.Groups.FindAsync(request.GroupId);
if (group == null)
{
    throw new EntityNotFoundException($"{nameof(Data.Models.Group)} not found.");
}
```

With the above code, when running the tests, any `BadRequestException` passes but any test that expects a `NotFound` response from the `EntityNotFoundException` class produces the following error:

```cs
Exception Message: 
        Test method MyProject.Test.Tests.Integration.Group.DeleteGroupTests.DeleteGroup_IdDoesNotExist_NotFound threw exception: 
        System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Error while copying content to a stream. ---> System.IO.IOException:  ---> MyProject.Data.Exceptions.EntityNotFoundException: Group not found.
      Stack Trace: 
        DeleteGroupCommandHandler.Handle(DeleteGroupCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) line 40
        RequestExceptionProcessorBehavior`2.Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate`1 next)
...
```

**EntityNotFoundException - Fails**

```cs
public class EntityNotFoundException : ExceptionBase
{
    private static string DefaultMessageHeader => "Not found";

    public override HttpStatusCode StatusCode => HttpStatusCode.NotFound;

    public EntityNotFoundException(string message, string messageHeader = null)
            : base(message, messageHeader ?? DefaultMessageHeader) { }
}
```

**BadRequestException - Passes**

```cs
public class BadRequestException : ExceptionBase
{
    private static string DefaultMessageHeader => "Bad Request";

    public override HttpStatusCode StatusCode => HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

    public BadRequestException(string message, string messageHeader = null)
            : base(message, messageHeader ?? DefaultMessageHeader) { }
}
```

What is the problem with the `EntityNotFoundException` class? Why do only those fail?

**Update 1**

Tests:

```cs
// FAILS
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(int.MaxValue)]
public async Task DeleteGroup_IdDoesNotExist_NotFound(int groupId)
{
    var response = await Client.DeleteAsync($"/api/groups/{groupId}");
    response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}

// PASSES
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(0)]
[DataRow(-1)]
public async Task DeleteGroup_InvalidId_BadRequest(int groupId)
{
    var response = await Client.DeleteAsync($"/api/groups/{groupId}");
    response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

Comment: What does your test look like?

Comment: Added the tests in Update 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55774998/1448448) to fix the tests but still unsure why the error happens only for the `EntityNotFoundException` exception classes and no others.

If anyone knows why the below code fixes the failing tests, I'd love to hear it.

The solution is to specify the `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` flag which is not available in `DeleteAsync`, so switch to `SendAsync` instead.

**From:**

```cs
using var response = await Client.DeleteAsync($"/api/groups/{groupId}");
```

**To:**

```cs
using var response = await Client.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, $"/api/groups/{groupId}"), HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```