# Getting the request origin in Express

Tags: express

How do I actually get the origin? When I use the following under `router.get('/', ...)`, it just returns undefined.

```
var origin = req.get('origin');
```

(I am trying to use the origin domain as a lookup key, to then construct the right URL parameters to post to an API)

Comment: are you setting `origin` in request header while sending the request. You might want to use req.hostname I guess.

Comment: do you want to expose the API to be accessed by only a particular domain?

Comment: `req.host` returns the domain that Express is running on, in my tests; I am trying to allow CORS so that the domain which makes an .ajax call to the domain hosting Express, is allowed access, and also is the hash key in a lookup.

Comment: I have this set in my app.js

`app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
  next();
});`

Comment: you will get `req.get(origin)` data once you deployed for client code to a server.

Comment: i have the same issue. i used to get origin event on local, but now i don't

Answer (score 5):

Add this expressJs middleware in the path of request. Make sure it is the first middleware request encounters.

```js
/**
 * Creates origin property on request object
 */
app.use(function (req, _res, next) {
  var protocol = req.protocol;

  var hostHeaderIndex = req.rawHeaders.indexOf('Host') + 1;
  var host = hostHeaderIndex ? req.rawHeaders[hostHeaderIndex] : undefined;

  Object.defineProperty(req, 'origin', {
    get: function () {
      if (!host) {
        return req.headers.referer ? req.headers.referer.substring(0, req.headers.referer.length - 1) : undefined;
      }
      else {
        return protocol + '://' + host;
      }
    }
  });

  next();
});
```

where app is express app or express router object.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to get the host/origin

**First Method:**

You have to retrieve it from the [HOST header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246859/http-1-0-vs-1-1/247026#247026).

```
var host = req.get('host');
```

If this is for supporting [cross-origin requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), you would instead use the `Origin` header.

```
var origin = req.get('origin');
```

**Second Method:**

you can also use:

```
var host = req.headers.host;
var origin = req.headers.origin;
```

**Extra Note:**

If you're looking for the client's IP, you can retrieve that with:

```
var userIP = req.socket.remoteAddress;
```

Answer (score 2):

`var origin = req.get('Origin')` works under `router.get` when the server (app.js in this case) has `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", <a single allowed domain here (or '*' for any domain)>);` inserted before its routes.