# Why cURL response from server is HTTP/1.0?

Tags: python, http, curl

I had created simple server in terminal

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

when I send command `curl -I http://localhost:8000`

and command result was a request:

`127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2016 14:53:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

but response was a `HTTP/1.0`

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.7.12
Date: Sun, 07 Aug 2016 10:02:08 GMT
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 9747
```

`curl -v http://localhost:8000`

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8000/
*   Trying ::1...
* connect to ::1 port 8000 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.7.12
< Date: Sun, 07 Aug 2016 10:02:23 GMT
< Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 9747
<
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"><html>
...
</html>
* Closing connection 0
```

How we can explain this? Why server response was not a `HTTP/1.1`

Comment: I've not used anything like this before in Python so I might be completely out of the ball park but from a Google search I found something that might explain it: [BaseHTTPRequestHandler.protocol_version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.protocol_version): "This specifies the HTTP protocol version used in responses." Perhaps there's a `protocol_version` property you can set for `SimpleHTTPServer` before you launch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl` uses HTTP/1.1 by default from version 7.33.0 (yours is 7.43.0). In `man curl`:

```
--http1.1
              (HTTP) Tells curl to use HTTP version 1.1. This is the internal default version. (Added in 7.33.0)
```

So `curl` will make a request with `HTTP/1.1` to your server.

This line

`127.0.0.1 - - [07/Aug/2016 14:53:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

is just a log entry which tells you that there is a request made with expected to get `HTTP/1.1` BUT it doesn't mean server must response with `HTTP/1.1`, see the link of Karoly Horvath for detail.

Looking at source code of `SimpleHTTPServer`, you can see there is a [default request version](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/BaseHTTPServer.py#l230) which is `HTTP/0.9`.

This `default_request_version` variable is then assigned to `self.request_version` in line 244.

The function which does the response is `send_response` and at line 402 there is a comparison with `HTTP/0.9`, this leads to the protocol version is `protocol_version` is `HTTP/1.0` in [line 515](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/BaseHTTPServer.py#l515)

Comment: Thank you, cuongnv!

Comment: Actually, curl has used HTTP/1.1 since a lot longer than so, like basically forever.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a version number, the server supports the older 1.0 protocol.

See [HTTP 1.0 vs 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246859/http-1-0-vs-1-1)

Comment: Thank you, Karoly!