# NET - HttpWebRequest host header order on TOP

Tags: c, header, httpwebrequest, host

For several days I have been trying to establish communication with the server using HttpWebRequest. I noticed that server isn't compliant with the protocol specification of the http in RFC. Therefore, I set tru in App.config:

```
<httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing = "true" />
```

After doing this, I received a *400* answer.
I noticed that I can communicate using curl software.
I set the same headings in my code - with no result.

Finally, I noticed that the order of the host header is a problem. If the *host* header is  after *POST / HTTP / 1.1*, the server responds is OK, but if it is at the end of all headers, then I get the code *400*.

Didn't work:

```
POST / HTTP / 1.1
User-Agent: curl / 7.52.1
Accept: * / *
Content-Type: text / xml; charset = ISO-8859-1
SOAPAction: ...
Host: 10.10.10.147
```

It works:

```
POST / HTTP / 1.1
Host: 10.10.10.147
User-Agent: curl / 7.52.1
Accept: * / *
Content-Type: text / xml; charset = ISO-8859-1
SOAPAction: ...
```

Is there any possibility to change the order of headers using HttpWebRequest?

Comment: It also works fine if there is no host header, so I tried: webRequest.Headers.Remove("Host");

Comment: How can you read in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246859/http-1-0-vs-1-1

A host header is not required in http 1.0.
I set the version to 1.0, and the host header is still sent and can't be deleted.