# when would you get a web request without a host name?

Tags: nginx

I've been reviewing some nginx configuration docs and i found this: 
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html
I'm specifically reading the section about rejecting requests that don't provide a host name.

I'm wondering how to generate these types of requests for testing purposes, and when would these types of request come in - in real life...aka do i need to care?

**What I've tried so far:**

I've added the following into my nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name "";
    return      444;
}
```

Then I tried to play around with curl and send a request with an empty host header like so:

```
curl --verbose --header 'Host:' 'http://192.1.6.1/test/hello'
```

That returns the error 400 bad request.

Comment: I would start by finding out why that bad request occurred.

Comment: In the olden days there was HTTP/1.0 which did not require a Host header. You could try `curl --http1.0`

Comment: that worked @RichardSmith.  and thanks for putting context around it by mentioning HTTP 1.0

Answer (score 0):

An old version of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.0) did not require a `Host` request header. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246859/http-1-0-vs-1-1) for details.

You can force `curl` to use HTTP/1.0 with the `--http1.0` command line option.